# Can I define boundedness in a topological vector space w.r.t. arbitrary point?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I have started reading Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, and in Section 1.6, he makes the following definition:

A subset $E$ of a topological vector space is said to be bounded iff for every open neighborhood $V$ of $0$, there exists an $s > 0$ such that for each $t > s$, we have $E\subseteq tV$.

**Question:** Since the open neighborhoods of $0$ completely determine the topology here, I have a hunch that instead of open neighborhoods of $0$, we could have taken any arbitrary point of the space. However, I am having trouble proving the equivalence. Any leads?

Comment: Directly scaling neighborhoods of other points wouldn't work.  Scaled neighborhoods of zero fill out the space whereas scaling neighborhoods of other points escape to infinity.  Draw a picture in $R$ or $R^2$.

Comment: @yoyo Oh yeah! I see it now. So, arbitrary points won't work here; we need neigborhoods of $0$, right?

Comment: It's worth pointing out, though, that you could indeed make this definition for an arbitrary point, if you simply translate it appropriately, so it becomes for some point $p$, and every neighborhood $V$ of $p$, there is an $s>0$ such that for $t>s$, we have $E\subseteq tV-tp$.  But that would be a little awkward and kind of pointless.

Comment: "Scaling" doesn't work in a topological space -- you need a normed-space structure or something. I suppose that you could replace the sets $tV$ with a bunch of sets $V(t)$, where $s < t$ implies $V(s) \subset V(t)$, and for every $P$ in your space, there's a $c$ with $P \in V(t)$ for all $t \ge c$. But defining something like that just seems contrived.

Comment: @JohnHughes its a topological vector space, not an arbitrary topological space.  I think OP just left off the word "vector" in the body, but the tag and the title both say vector space.

Comment: Ah...I mistakenly read the actual question rather than the title, :(